Definition of Moore-Penrose inverse for unbounded self-adjoint operators?
I know there is a concept of Moore-Penrose or pseudoinverse of a matrix. I would like to know if one can define it for densely defined unbounded self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces as well. References are also welcomed.

An obvious generalization exists for compact operators via their singular value decomposition. You find explanations on the wikipedia pages on the SVD https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition . But this doesn't answer your question. For the unbounded case I don't know of a sensible generalization.

The usual definition of pseudoinverse seems to work fine for me, as long as you just relax the requirements that everything is bounded to being closed and densely defined.

(I guess one also needs to slightly relax the requirement that $AA^+$ and $A^+A$ are self-adjoint to their closures being self-adjoint.)
